# Errors with VHDL Script Syntax

Tags: vhdl

I have this code i want to do an LSFR but I have several problems, including:

> ERROR:HDLParsers:3010 - "C:/Users/user/Documents/tp_vhdl/median_LSFR/LSFR.vhd" Line 18. Entity LFSR does not exist.
>   ERROR:HDLParsers:3312 - "C:/Users/user/Documents/tp_vhdl/median_LSFR/LSFR.vhd" Line 19. Undefined symbol 'std_logic_vector'.
>   ERROR:HDLParsers:1209 - "C:/Users/user/Documents/tp_vhdl/median_LSFR/LSFR.vhd" Line 19. std_logic_vector: Undefined symbol (last report in this block)
>   ERROR:HDLParsers:3312 - "C:/Users/user/Documents/tp_vhdl/median_LSFR/LSFR.vhd" Line 20. Undefined symbol 'std_logic'.
>   ERROR:HDLParsers:1209 - "C:/Users/user/Documents/tp_vhdl/median_LSFR/LSFR.vhd" Line 20. std_logic: Undefined symbol (last report in this block)
>   ERROR:HDLParsers:3312 - "C:/Users/user/Documents/tp_vhdl/median_LSFR/LSFR.vhd" Line 24. Undefined symbol 's_xor1'.

The code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;


entity LSFR is port (
    clk : in std_logic;
    reset,en : in std_logic;
    de1,de2 : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0)
    );
end LSFR;


architecture arch of LFSR is
signal etatpresent, etatfutur : std_logic_vector(16 downto 1);
signal s_xor1, s_xor2, s_xor3 : std_logic;
begin

-- Calcul intermediaire des ou exclusifs
s_xor1 <= etatpresent(15) xor etatpresent(1);
s_xor2 <= etatpresent(14) xor etatpresent(1);
s_xor3 <= etatpresent(12) xor etatpresent(1);

-- Calcul de l'état futur en fonction de l'état présent et des ou exclusifs

process(etatpresent) begin

etatfutur(16) <= etatpresent(1);
etatfutur(1) <= etatpresent(2);
etatfutur (2) <= etatpresent(3);
etatfutur (3) <= etatpresent(4);
etatfutur (4) <= etatpresent(5);
etatfutur (5) <= etatpresent(6);
etatfutur (6) <= etatpresent(7);
etatfutur (7) <= etatpresent(8);
etatfutur (8) <= etatpresent(9);
etatfutur (9) <= etatpresent(10);
etatfutur (10) <= etatpresent(11);
etatfutur (11) <= s_xor3;
s_xor3 <= etatpresent(12);
etatfutur (12) <= etatpresent(13);
etatfutur (13) <= s_xor2;
s_xor2 <= etatpresent(14);
etatfutur (14) <= s_xor1;
s_xor1 <= etatpresent(15);
etatfutur (15) <= etatpresent(16);

end process;

process(reset) begin
                if (reset = '1' ) then
                    etatfutur <="0000000000000001"; 
                end if ;
end process;


-- cablage des deux sorties
de1(2 downto 0) <= etatpresent(16 downto 14);
de2 (2 downto 0) <= etatpresent(3 downto 1);
end arch;
```

Comment: you have declared your libraries twice.

Comment: Pleased read the error message carefully. It is just a typo in LSFR / LFSR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you don't identify line numbers and they don't match the first error is LFSR is not a declared entity for the architecture arch as Martin Zobel indicates. It appears to be a misspelled entity name in the entity declaration and it's end statement.

Without resorting to an Internet search to identify the VHDL tool producing the error messages it doesn't appear quite standard compliant, Maria may be on to something in her comment, having recognized the error messages origin.

Normally a duplicate library name in a context clause is ignored, as are replicated declarations in use clauses in the same inner declarative region.

Straightening out the entity name and context clause (by removing superfluous elements):

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity LFSR is  -- was LSFR is port (
    port (
        clk:       in  std_logic;
        reset, en: in  std_logic;
        de1, de2:  out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0)
    );
end entity LFSR; -- was  end LSFR;

architecture arch of LFSR is    -- Line 16,  LFSR doesn't match LSFR
    signal etatpresent, etatfutur:  std_logic_vector(16 downto 1);
    signal s_xor1, s_xor2, s_xor3:  std_logic;
begin

-- Calcul intermediaire des ou exclusifs
    s_xor1 <= etatpresent(15) xor etatpresent(1);
    s_xor2 <= etatpresent(14) xor etatpresent(1);
    s_xor3 <= etatpresent(12) xor etatpresent(1);

-- Calcul de l'état futur en fonction de l'état présent et des ou exclusifs

    process (etatpresent) 
    begin
        etatfutur(16) <= etatpresent(1);
        etatfutur(1) <= etatpresent(2);
        etatfutur (2) <= etatpresent(3);
        etatfutur (3) <= etatpresent(4);
        etatfutur (4) <= etatpresent(5);
        etatfutur (5) <= etatpresent(6);
        etatfutur (6) <= etatpresent(7);
        etatfutur (7) <= etatpresent(8);
        etatfutur (8) <= etatpresent(9);
        etatfutur (9) <= etatpresent(10);
        etatfutur (10) <= etatpresent(11);
        etatfutur (11) <= s_xor3;
        s_xor3 <= etatpresent(12);
        etatfutur (12) <= etatpresent(13);
        etatfutur (13) <= s_xor2;
        s_xor2 <= etatpresent(14);
        etatfutur (14) <= s_xor1;
        s_xor1 <= etatpresent(15);
        etatfutur (15) <= etatpresent(16);
    end process;

    process (reset, clk)   -- added clock to sensitivity list
    begin
        if reset = '1'  then
            etatpresent <= "0000000000000001";  -- was etatfutur
        elsif rising_edge(clk) and en = '1' then
            etatpresent <= etatfutur;
        end if;
    end process;

-- cablage des deux sorties
    de1(2 downto 0) <= etatpresent(16 downto 14);
    de2 (2 downto 0) <= etatpresent(3 downto 1);

end architecture arch;
```

Gives us something that analyzes. Note I also added clk to the process sensitivity list, corrected the reset and added the etatpresent register.

So does it work? We can find out by creating a small testbench and simulating:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity lfsr_tb is
end entity;

architecture fum of lfsr_tb is
    signal clk:     std_logic := '0';
    signal reset:   std_logic;
    signal en:      std_logic;
    signal de1:     std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
    signal de2:     std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
begin

DUT:
    entity work.lfsr
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            reset => reset,
            en => en,
            de1 => de1,
            de2 => de2
        );
CLOCK:
    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        clk <= not clk;
        if now > 450 ns then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;
STIMULI:
    process
    begin
        wait for 11 ns;
        reset <= '1';
        en <= '0';
        wait for 20 ns;
        reset <= '0';
        wait for 20 ns;
        en <= '1';
        wait for 100 ns;
        en <= '0';
        wait for 40 ns;
        en <= '1';
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

And simulating that gives us something that doesn't look to good:

[image: lfsr_tb_fail.png]

So what happened?

A closer look at the unlabeled first process in arch of lfsr shows there are duplicate drivers for s_xor1, s_xor_2 and s_xor3, as well as the three of these missing for the sensitivity list (they show up on the right hand side expressions of assignments).

Without having a reference to the LFSR algorithm you're implementing we can simple add the missing sensitivity list items, and comment out the drivers:

```
-- Calcul de l'état futur en fonction de l'état présent et des ou exclusifs

    process (etatpresent, s_xor1, s_xor2, s_xor3) 
    begin
        etatfutur(16) <= etatpresent(1);
        etatfutur(1) <= etatpresent(2);
        etatfutur (2) <= etatpresent(3);
        etatfutur (3) <= etatpresent(4);
        etatfutur (4) <= etatpresent(5);
        etatfutur (5) <= etatpresent(6);
        etatfutur (6) <= etatpresent(7);
        etatfutur (7) <= etatpresent(8);
        etatfutur (8) <= etatpresent(9);
        etatfutur (9) <= etatpresent(10);
        etatfutur (10) <= etatpresent(11);
        etatfutur (11) <= s_xor3;
        -- s_xor3 <= etatpresent(12);
        etatfutur (12) <= etatpresent(13);
        etatfutur (13) <= s_xor2;
        -- s_xor2 <= etatpresent(14);
        etatfutur (14) <= s_xor1;
        -- s_xor1 <= etatpresent(15);
        etatfutur (15) <= etatpresent(16);
    end process;
```

And that gives us an error free waveform:

[image: lfsr_tb_fixed.png]

You'll need to validate the LFSR operation against the algorithm's specification.

Note how having en invalid for two clocks worked.

Answer (score 1):

You have spelt LFSR wrong in the entity. ("LSFR")